# Application.Run(new Form1()) stops execution of further code

Tags: multithreading, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have created an Application where I am opening new WinFrom through Code.
Problem what I am facing is when I open new Winform with Application.Run() method, here form gets open but after that it stops the execution of current thread, means it is not executing any line of code after `Application.Run(geMBrowserForm);`

I am using STA thread to open new WinForm.

If I use new NewFrom().show(), it shows new from but the WebBrowser in form is not Navigating to the URL, even WebBrowser.DocumentCompletedis not getting fired.

Please Find below Code what I have done.

Opening New Form:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        GeMBrowserForm geMBrowserForm = new GeMBrowserForm();
        Application.Run(geMBrowserForm);
        geM_Processor.UpdateProductPriceInServer(productInfo, geMUserDTOs[0], geMBrowserForm.gemBrowser);
        Application.Exit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: This is how it works. No surprise there. [Application.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run). Then, if you crate a WebBrowser control in a thread other than the main (UI) thread, the WebBrowser won't work. Why do you feel need to create a  WebBrowser in a new thread? It's event driven, it won't block your UI. If you need to execute code on an event, maybe that code could be threaded.

Comment: I have such requirement where for multiple user application does work with Task(TPL) per User, show I will not have main thread, that is why I need to create additional STA thread to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with *multiple user application*. Usually, it's an application that can be active on multiple machines, using common resources at the same time. Or it's a service. Or a server software. Anyway, you're not using the TPL here. There are means to execute a WebBrowser control in a thread other than the UI thread. I don't think you want to go there. In production.

Comment: let me give you be exact scenario, I have 5 users I am logging them to a particular website but as I want that they should not go in queue (like for loop) I am using Tasks, I am putting each user in Task and run it, then it will perform whatever actions they supposed to do. So now each user needs one web browser so I am trying to run new form which contains web browser  and I am trying to invoke it then navigate to URL but it is not firing DocumnetCompleted event so I am unable to do further actions.

Comment: What do you mean with *I have 5 users*? Are you running your app in 5 machines operated by 5 users independently or you're referring to Web *Users*: meaning 5 online accounts that you have to login to some web service? In any case, you don't need threads for this. No matter the threading pattern. If you're saying that you have to throttle connections/IP addresses/proxies to try to prevent your *Users* from being banned, you may want to thread you IP selector/tracer/spoofer/whatever, adding timeouts as required.